# android animation in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an animation like this

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animView);
anim_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.drawable.bounce);

public void upAnim(View view){

    img.clearAnimation();
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
    anim_up.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim_up.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    img.startAnimation(anim_up);

}
```

and i want to do this animation in asynctask, but I have no idea how do this. I tried a lot of solutions...
Can someone please share some sample code on how to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Animations and UI drawing is always done in main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matthias has mentioned in the question's comments, all animations should be done on the UI thread. For an AsyncTask, the doInBackground() method is called on the background thread whereas methods like onPreExecute(), onProgressUpdate(), onPostExecute() and onCancelled() are called on UI thread. Based on when you want to show your animation, override the appropriate AsyncTask method and make the call accordingly.

Learn more about the lifecycle of AsyncTask [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).