# AnimationDrawable not showing when used with an AsyncTask

Tags: android, animationdrawable

I'm trying to show an animation with `AnimationDrawable` in my `Activity` which works fine when i'm not using an `AsyncTask` with a callback interface.My code for the animation is,

```
img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gif);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
Handler h=new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    },100);
```

If i start the AsyncTask the animation won't run.It just shows the first frame.Is there a way to make the animation play (preferably) without removing the callback?

Comment: Post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

All animations should be done on the ui thread.  So onPre and onPost Execute should have your animation code in it

I found this:

[This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224014/android-animation-in-asynctask)